# extend Android View while using XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to use Android's typical XML to define my layout but I need to override `onScrollChanged()` in `ScrollView`. Here is my current attempt which generates a class cast exception:

```
class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

private final AbstractChartActivity abstractChartActivity;

public MyHorizontalScrollView(AbstractChartActivity abstractChartActivity, 
   Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.abstractChartActivity = abstractChartActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    String tag = (String) this.getTag();

    // if the instance is listening to the column header scroll, then
    // move the body
    if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase(AbstractChartActivity.COL_HEADER_SCROLL)) {
        abstractChartActivity.goodiBodyHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(l, 0);
    } else {
        // if the instance is listening to the body scroll, then move
        // the header
        abstractChartActivity.columnHeaderHorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(l, 0);
    }
}

}
```

and the layout...

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/blank_cell_above_labels_table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/column_header_horizontal_scroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blank_cell_above_labels_table" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/column_header_table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

This line throws a class cast exception because `MyHorizontalScrollView` extends `HorizontalScrollView` but is not exactly the same type.

```
columnHeaderHorizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.column_header_horizontal_scroll);
```

I have this all working by programmatically implementing the layout. But I worry it will be a maintenance nightmare so I want to shift functionality to XML where possible.

How can I extend an Android class and use it in XML?

Thanks

Comment: use `<com.example.app.MyHorizontalScrollView` in xml where `com.example.app` is package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<com.example.app.MyHorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/column_header_horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/blank_cell_above_labels_table" >
```

Where `com.example.app` is the package name where `MyHorizontalScrollView` is.

Then

```
columnHeaderHorizontalScrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.column_header_horizontal_scroll);
```

Also add 2 more constructors

```
public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}
```

You may want to read a book my Retro Meir Professional Android Application Development. Chapter 4

Comment: answer works great but there are actually 3 additional constructors. In addition to above, implement  
    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);

}

Comment: @JeffofBrooklyn its only 3 constructors that's all you need. you can have additional constructors also. overloaded ones. Read the book by retro meir. Chapter 4